# How to go back to my account?

Tags: 14.04, boot, login, guest-session

I was importing something to my computer which Ubuntu alerted only 9.5MB of space is available on the root drive. Then Ubuntu freezed so I turned my computer off using the turn on key. After I wanted to run my computer again, when logged in to my account the background appered but not the desktop nor the bars at the left and at the top appeared. When I tried to log in to the guest account I could do it with no problem but, obviously, I do not have access to my files.

P.S: I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
P.S 2: My window manager is gnome.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think its just your window manager is not able to start.
I assume u can open terminal by `Ctrl+Alt+t`(as was able to when i faced such issue sometime back). if you can just try to start your window manager(i am not sure but think that is unity or compiz so try running them). 
if you are not able to do so u can start nautilus(file manager) and access your files or install gnome-shell with command `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`.

Comment: Thanks for helping but it did not work.

Comment: can you give more info on which solution did not work. just curious.

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+T` So I used `Ctrl-Alt-F1` and I'm waiting for installing gnome

Comment: @NavidRashidian: Apparently you should delete stuff, not install.

Comment: Just a head up if the space in disk is an issue here which looks very possible installing gnome will not help. so try deleting stuff from your main partition. try "sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean" also move things from your root drive to other partitions using command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

your home directory space is full so will not able to login until you delete some data from your home direcory . so try to delete some data from disk using any method liveCD or `Ctrl-Alt-F1` or boot into rescue mode etc .
similar problem discussed here so look into given link . https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/3061

or delete using root user . you can login with root account because system  keeps by default 5% free space for super user .